# Migrate taxonomy with depth

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, migrations

I need to migrate a CSV file of 3000 Taxonomy terms with depth of 5 levels deep.
This is a small sample of the CSV comma-separated values file.

```
About Us
About Us, Our Programs
About Us, Our History, Timeline
Mission
Mission, Community
```

I want these values to be inserted into a Vocabulary, It should have the depth and it should ignore parent terms it has already created. It should look just like this in Drupal

```
About Us
-Our Programs
-Our History
--Timeline
Mission
-Community
```

I created a simple migrate yml file that can do this but I had to restructure 
the CSV file a lot and it is too much manual work. Can regex or something search
for the comma delimiter and make the term after a comma a child of the term in 
front of it? And can it skip or ignore parent terms it already created? Here is my migration and csv file.

```
id: vocab
label: Migrate terms from the source CSV to taxonomy terms
migration_group: migrated_terms
source:
   plugin: csv
   path: 'public://csv/vocab.csv'
   header_row_count: 1
   keys:
      - uuid
   column_names:
     0:
       uuid: UUID
     1:
       vid: VID
     2:
       name: NAME
     3:
       parent: PARENT
destination:
   plugin: entity:taxonomy_term
process:
   vid: vid
   name: name
   parent:
      plugin: migration
      migration: vocab
      source: parent
```

csv file

```
"uuid","vid","name","parent"
"100","myvocab","About Us"  
"101","myvocab","Our Programs","100"
"102","myvocab","Our History","100"
"103","myvocab","Mission"
"104","myvocab","Community","103"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the example in web/core/modules/taxonomy/migrations/d7_taxonomy_term.yml

It sets a term parent_id by looking it up in the same migration:

```
  parent_id:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: process
      source: parent
    -
      plugin: migration_lookup
      migration: d7_taxonomy_term
  parent:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 0
    source: '@parent_id'
```

For your case you only need to change the migration name:

```
    plugin: migration_lookup
    migration: vocab
```

You can use the [Migrate Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_devel) module to inspect the migrations while working on them.